# Moving shape not working on anonymous keylistener even using setFocus

Tags: java, swing, awt

I used anonymous keyListener but the shape is not moving. When I run my program it will run fine and I can view the fill arc shape with color. However the problem is with keyPressed method it seems it's not trigerring when I pressed arrow keys. I also used setFocus on my Jpanel as I read some of the answers on the web. Still I got the same report. Any help is much appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public class PacMan {

    public PacMan()
    {
        initializeUI();  
    }

    public void initializeUI ()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PacMan");
        PacManObject pacman = new PacManObject();
        pacman.setFocusable(true);
        pacman.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(pacman); 

        pacman.addKeyListener(new PacManObject());


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PacMan();
            }

        };EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }

    public class PacManObject extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

        int xLocation = 100;
        int yLocation = 100;
        int mouth = 265;

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)
        {
            super.paintComponent(graphics);
            graphics.setColor(Color.yellow);
            graphics.fillArc(xLocation, yLocation, 100, 100, 45, mouth);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyboard) {

             if(keyboard.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                 System.out.print("hello");
                 xLocation += 30;
                 System.out.print(xLocation);
                 repaint();
             }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: `... it's not working fine` is going to help as much as "my computer  doesn't work". Be more specific, e.g. what do you get and what do you expect instead? Did you debug your code to see whether the event is triggered at all?

Comment: @Thomas okay I edited my question feel free to check

Comment: Did you check it is called when pressing any other key?

Comment: @Thomas Yes. it's being called when I debug using the System.out.print. Meaning the keyPressed seems working but there's a problem moving the shape

Comment: `there's a problem moving the shape` - again, please be more specific. What doesn't work? Is nothing being drawn? If so is `paintComponent()` being called? Is the shape drawn in the wrong location? - Besides that: your code structure is really odd, I suggest reading up on object oriented design (e.g. the location should probably be part of `PacmanObject`, you'll see that when you start adding ghosts). Additionally try to learn how to use a debugger (e.g. from within Netbeans or Eclipse) which will make stepping through your code easier.

Comment: @Thomas Okay meaning the shape specifically the fillArc is not moving to the right. Are you aware of pacman game? That's the concept behind this project. Meaning the shape specifically pacman will move to the right when user press keys specifically right arrow.

Comment: Yes I still know Pacman ;) - So, again I'll have to say: use a debugger. Is `xLocation` being changed by the key event? If yes what is the value of `xLocation` when painting afterwards?

Comment: @Thomas Yes the pacman's xLocation is changing by  the value I declare. Example the xLocation is 130 it becomes now 160 then 190 and so on. As i press the right key. Again I already did this step before I posted  my problem in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You're creating two PacManObject objects

```
PacManObject pacman = new PacManObject(); // **** here ****
pacman.setFocusable(true);
pacman.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(600,600);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(pacman); 

pacman.addKeyListener(new PacManObject());  // **** and here ****
```

when you should really be creating **only one** since by creating two, you change the state of the 2nd one, but draw with the first one, so the changes will not be shown on the screen. So instead do something like:

```
PacManObject pacman = new PacManObject(); 
pacman.setFocusable(true);
pacman.setRequestFocusEnabled(true);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(600,600);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.add(pacman); 

pacman.addKeyListener(pacman);  // **** note change ****
```

Better still is to not have your GUI classes implement your listener interfaces as doing so is giving them too much responsibility -- i.e., it violates OOP principle's single-responsibility rule for classes.

Also, better to use Key Bindings as the dup's will tell you.

Better to use a Swing Timer as your game loop, and not to rely on the key presses, as the latter will lead to a delay in initial movement.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PacMan2 extends JPanel implements DirMappable {
    private static final int PREF_W = 600;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final Color BG = Color.DARK_GRAY;
    private static final int ANIMATION_DELAY = 15;
    private int pmX = 100;
    private int pmY = 100;
    private EnumMap<Direction, Boolean> dirMap = new EnumMap<>(Direction.class);

    private MyPacMan myPacMan = new MyPacMan(pmX, pmY, 30);
    private Timer animationTimer;

    public PacMan2() {
        setBackground(BG);

        setKeyBindings();

        animationTimer = new Timer(ANIMATION_DELAY, new AnimationListener(this));
        animationTimer.start();
    }

    private void setKeyBindings() {
        // fill the dirMap with false's -- no initial motion
        for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            dirMap.put(dir, Boolean.FALSE);
        }

        // associate key code with Direction
        Map<Integer, Direction> keyToDir = new HashMap<>();
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_UP, Direction.UP);
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, Direction.DOWN);
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, Direction.LEFT);
        keyToDir.put(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, Direction.RIGHT);

        // get InputMap and ActionMap for binding
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        final InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        final ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

        // loop through the keyToDir Map and set up bindings
        boolean[] keyPressed = { true, false };
        for (Integer keyCode : keyToDir.keySet()) {
            Direction dir = keyToDir.get(keyCode);
            for (boolean onKeyPress : keyPressed) {
                // to make it clear how bindings work
                boolean onKeyRelease = !onKeyPress; 
                KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, onKeyRelease);
                Object key = keyStroke.toString();
                inputMap.put(keyStroke, key);
                // I prefer to use positive boolean variable for Action -- just a bit confusing
                actionMap.put(key, new KeyBindingsAction(this, dir, onKeyPress));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        myPacMan.draw(g2); // have our pac man draw itself
    }

    // safest way to set the GUI's size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    public void put(Direction dir, boolean pressed) {
        dirMap.put(dir, pressed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean get(Direction dir) {
        return dirMap.get(dir);
    }

    @Override
    public void move(Direction dir) {
        myPacMan.move(dir); // move our pacman 
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        PacMan2 mainPanel = new PacMan2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pac Man");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}

class MyPacMan {
    private static final Color COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final int STEP = 3; // moves faster if this is larger
    private int x;
    private int y;

    // for efficiency, draw PacMan as a BufferedImage 
    // if we want mouth to open and close, and if we want to
    // have it change direction, we'll need a Map of images associated with
    // the Direction enum
    private BufferedImage pacManImage; 

    public MyPacMan(int x, int y, int w) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        double h = w;
        double start = 45;
        double extent = 360 - 2 * 45;
        int type = Arc2D.PIE;
        Shape shape = new Arc2D.Double(0, 0, w, h, start, extent, type);
        pacManImage = new BufferedImage(w, w, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = pacManImage.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(COLOR);
        // smooth drawing with key anti-aliasing
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.fill(shape);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public void move(Direction dir) {
        x += dir.getIncrX() * STEP;
        y += dir.getIncrY() * STEP;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        if (pacManImage != null) {
            g2.drawImage(pacManImage, x, y, null);
        }
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

}

enum Direction {
    UP(0, -1), DOWN(0, 1), LEFT(-1, 0), RIGHT(1, 0);
    private int incrX;
    private int incrY;

    private Direction(int incrX, int incrY) {
        this.incrX = incrX;
        this.incrY = incrY;
    }

    public int getIncrX() {
        return incrX;
    }

    public int getIncrY() {
        return incrY;
    }
}

// use an interface to encapsulate the methods of the GUI that need to be
// exposed to the helper classes
interface DirMappable {
    void put(Direction dir, boolean pressed);

    boolean get(Direction dir);

    void move(Direction dir);

    void repaint();
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class KeyBindingsAction extends AbstractAction {
    private Direction dir;
    private boolean pressed;
    private DirMappable dirMappable;

    public KeyBindingsAction(DirMappable dirMappable, Direction dir, boolean pressed) {
        this.dirMappable = dirMappable;
        this.dir = dir;
        this.pressed = pressed;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        dirMappable.put(dir, pressed);
    }
}

class AnimationListener implements ActionListener {
    private DirMappable dirMappable;

    public AnimationListener(DirMappable dirMappable) {
        this.dirMappable = dirMappable;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        boolean repaint = false;
        for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            if (dirMappable.get(dir)) {
                dirMappable.move(dir);
                repaint = true;
            }
        }
        if (repaint) {
            dirMappable.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However your answer is too complicated and I cannot even understand. :). I just need simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd have to reiterate that your code structure is quite odd.
One problem is that `Pacman` extends `JPanel` - just why eludes me.

However, that's part of the problem since `Pacman` is never added to any frame or window and thus calling `repaint()` on that panel won't do anything.

Instead call `pacman.repaint()` or `frame.repaint()` (both need to be final in that case).

Comment: oops sorry about that. Didn't notice.Okay I update my code.